# How to replace array value with array value [have two array]

Tags: php, arrays

I try this array with `array_merge()` not working.

I have array (array one);

```
Array (
    [0] => mf_3
    [1] => mf_2
    [2] => mf_1
    [3] => mf_7
    [4] => mf_6
    [5] => mf_4
)
```

And on array again (second array),

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => review_smartphone_display
            [label] => Layar
            [post_type] => review_smartphone
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => review_smartphone_launch
            [label] => Peluncuran
            [post_type] => review_smartphone
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => review_smartphone_platform
            [label] => Platform
            [post_type] => review_smartphone
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => review_smartphone_camera
            [label] => Kamera
            [post_type] => review_smartphone
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => review_smartphone_design
            [label] => Desain
            [post_type] => review_smartphone
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => review_smartphone_battery
            [label] => Baterai
            [post_type] => review_smartphone
        )
)
```

Now, how to replace second array **[id]** with value from array one.

I want the result like this;

```
Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => mf_3
                [name] => review_smartphone_display
                [label] => Layar
                [post_type] => review_smartphone
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => mf_2
                [name] => review_smartphone_launch
                [label] => Peluncuran
                [post_type] => review_smartphone
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => mf_1
                [name] => review_smartphone_platform
                [label] => Platform
                [post_type] => review_smartphone
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => mf_7
                [name] => review_smartphone_camera
                [label] => Kamera
                [post_type] => review_smartphone
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => mf_6
                [name] => review_smartphone_design
                [label] => Desain
                [post_type] => review_smartphone
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => mf_4
                [name] => review_smartphone_battery
                [label] => Baterai
                [post_type] => review_smartphone
            )
    )
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried writing a simple foreach loop?

Comment: You have to use for loop for that. The logic is not so difficult that you have to use function.

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan You dont HAVE to use a FOR loop for that

Comment: difference between foreach and for loop. I am just asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of foreach like below

```
foreach($first_array as $index => $farray)
{
     $second_array[$index]->id = $farray;
}
```

Comment: It might if `$second_array[$index]->id = $farray;`

Comment: It might if `$index => $farray`.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectsss like i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($first_array as $key => $value) {
    $second_array[$key]->id = $value;  
}
```

Comment: Its nice to add just a little description of what you did and why